# Lubuntu not starting GUI after install on Hyper-V

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, hyper-v

After installing Lubuntu Desktop from Ubunut's `mini.iso` on virtual machine on Windows 10 host with Hyper-V, only cli is booting, but not the GUI. How do I boot GUI from the cli?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is installed with lubuntu desktop, so posting as a comment. It is probably a command like `lxsession`, have you tried that?

Comment: I've tried `lxsession` and `startx`, both commands not found.